# Why can't we see how other people have flagged a post?

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

If I go into the 10k tools, I can see the number of flags for offensive and spam for all flagged posts. Is there a reason why I can't have this information in the flag window as well, so before I choose a reason, I can see how other people have flagged a post? It would be just like the close window - it shows you the number of people who have voted for each of the close reasons and the total number of people who voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to work that way - anyone with enough rep to flag could see the current flag count. AFAIK, it was [changed to the current system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/) in an attempt to reduce flag abuse...

(See [the discussion on Raising a Red Flag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/#comments) for more info/opinions)

Comment: But I think OP is talking about 10k-tools, right?

Comment: No. I'm talking about in the drop down menu when you click flag.